# Tkinter: Problems when saving multiple Entry widgets to list

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm developing an interface where the user will select points from a displayed image. A list with the selected points is shown in the right side of the window. Each time the user clicks on a point, the list is updated to add the new point. Points in the list are shown as coordinates, and next to the coordinates there's an Entry widget so the user can assign a text label to that specific point.

[image]

Since I can't know how many points the user is going to select, and I can't know if the user is going to fill the name Entry right after selecting a point or in the end after selecting all points, the text from the Entry widgets is to be read after the user presses the 'CONTINUE' button.

What I've been doing so far is: each time a new point is added, ie, each time a new Entry widget is created, the widget is saved to a list. This is the function executed every time a new point is added:

```
def _update_point_list(self):
    self.dynamic_frame.pack_forget()
    self.dynamic_frame.destroy()
    self.dynamic_frame = Frame(self.Fpoints)
    self.dynamic_frame.pack()

    for coo, i in zip(self.dynamic_points, range(len(self.dynamic_points))):
        L = Label(self.dynamic_frame, text=str([coo[0], coo[1]]))
        T = Entry(self.dynamic_frame, width=15)
        T.insert(INSERT, "Target name")
        B = Button(
            self.dynamic_frame,
            text='\xe2\x98\x92'.decode('utf8'),
            command=lambda i=i: self._button_remove_point(i))
        L.grid(row=i + 1, column=1)
        T.grid(row=i + 1, column=2)
        B.grid(row=i + 1, column=3)
        print T
        self.entries.append(T)

    if len(self.dynamic_points) > 0:
        self.cont.configure(state=ACTIVE)
        self.label.configure(
            text='\n              Selected points              \n')
    else:
        self.cont.configure(state=DISABLED)
        self.label.configure(
            text='\n            No points selected            \n')
```

The 'CONTINUE' button, when pressed, calls the following function:

```
def _read_data(self):
    for t in self.entries:
        self.labels.append(t.get())
```

However, when I run this, I get the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1489, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "/media/Fran/dataproc/timeseries/astrointerface.py", line 202, in _read_data
self.labels.append(t.get())
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 2475, in get
return self.tk.call(self._w, 'get')
TclError: invalid command name ".140339446529128.140339400493320.140339400493896.140339400493608"
```

If I print 'self.labels', it shows:

```
.140339446529128.140339400493320.140339400493896.140339400493608
```

Even though I know I could get past this issue by simply adding another button to the right of the Entry to "load" the target name, I would prefer this to be done with one single click. However, I'm not seeing my error in the code.

I've been looking at similar answers on the site and all of them use adding the Entry widgets to a list, so I really have no idea what could be going on here.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: All of the Entry IDs have been joined into a single string --> TclError: invalid command name ".140339446529128.140339400493320.140339400493896.140339400493608"  Try with one Entry only, remove the Entry's contents in _read_data() and  just reuse the same widget.

Comment: Please read [_How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: "invalid command name ".xxxxx"" usually means you are trying to call a method on a deleted widget. Is this code running after the entry widgets have been destroyed?

Comment: To analyze your problem better, a bit more code would be helpful. What happens before `_read_data` is called and after the entries have been added to the list? also try printing `t` before getting the entry data to check if it is the expected type.

Comment: @BryanOakley You are right. Every time a new point is added, the list of points is updated with new Entry widgets. I'm probably just reading a bunch of destroyed widgets from my list. Thank you.

Comment: @R4PH43L I added the code to show the complete function that is called when a point is added. I think the problem is that I'm creating new Entry widgets every time I update the point list, so the widgets that were already on the list are destroyed.

Comment: @CurlyJoe trying with just one Entry made me realize that the problem is I'm destroying/creating new widgets every time a new point is added. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: When destroying the parent frame, do you also reinitialize your entry list? `self.entries = []` after destroying the frame in `def _update_point_list(self)`

Comment: @R4PH43L no, the list is initialized when the Interface object is initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_update_point_list` destroys the `dynamic_frame` and in the first for loop you append the created entries to `self.entries`. So your old entries (destroyed as children of dynamic frame) are still inside the list. Setting `self.entries = []` after `self.dynamic_frame.destroy()` inside `_update_point_list` should solve your problem.

From effbot documentation:

> destroy() [#]
>
>
> Destroys the widget. The widget is removed from the screen, and all resources associated with the widget are released.